# Relative clause and omission in news article

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis

I have ***two*** questions regarding relative clauses (which I believe they are).

Question 1:
From [an article in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/02/china-confirms-death-of-uighur-man-whose-family-says-was-held-in-xinjiang-camps)

> The Chinese government has taken the rare step of formally confirming to the UN the death of a Uighur man whose family believe had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017.

Here it says

> " ... a Uighur man whose family believe had been held in..."

and here is what I'd rewrite as I understand the sentence:

> "... Uighur man whose family believe (that) he had been held in..."

If I understood correctly, why is the subject 'he' omitted?
If not, what is grammatical rule behind the original sentence from the Guardian?

Question 2:
From [an article in the Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/u-s-blacklists-chinese-entities-it-says-are-aiding-weapons-program-11617899231?mod=e2tw)

> The Biden administration on Thursday barred U.S. companies from supplying Chinese entities it said were building supercomputers to help Beijing develop new weapons of mass destruction, including nuclear devices.

Here it says

> "...Chinese entities it said were building supercomputers..."

and here is how I understand the sentence:

> "... Chinese entities which the Biden administration said were building supercomputers..."

‘which’ here is 'entities' is how I understand it.
Is this correct? If it is, what is ‘it said’? Is it just an embedded clause?
What grammar is behind this one?

Comment: As for why *he* is omitted, imagine a simpler sentence: **This is a man who eats fish.**  Clearly "this is a man" is the main clause, and "who eats fish" is a adjective clause, so it doesn't get a subject like *he*.  Incorrectly adding the subject again, like *This is a man who he eats fish* is a common error of English learners.  The sentence with "whose family believes" is exactly the same way.

Comment: @stangdon I know simple relative clauses but for the Guardian one, as far as I know, it should be separated into '...the death of a Uighur man.' + ' His family believe (that) he had been held ...'.  So 'His' becomes 'whose' to form relative clause. But then why is 'he' omitted? is my question.

Comment: It would certainly be simpler and clearer if they had separated it into two sentences instead of stuffing the Chinese government, the UN, the death, the man, a family, and an internment camp all into one sentence, but it does technically work as one sentence.

Comment: @Anatolia "He" must be omitted because the embedded clause already has "whose" as subject, and a clause can't have two subjects. See my answer.

Comment: @BillJ I've read your answer but I cannot understand it. As for your comment above saying "...the embedded clause already has "whose" as subject...', isn't 'whose' a possessive 'adjective'? I think 'whose family' would be the subject of 'believe'. To make it clear, would you write the original sentence into separate sentences? like I did above as '...the death of a Uighur man.' + ' His family believe (that) he had been held ...'

Comment: @stangdon It seems your simplified example might not be a good analogy for the sentence with "whose".  The fact that FumbleFingers believes it's grammatical (but ugly) both with and without "he", while Kate Bunting prefers the version with "he" (as do I), suggests that native speakers' intuitions don't line up with the theory that you and BillJ are proposing here - and that suggests the theory is flawed, unfortunately, because the purpose of a theory of syntax is to explain how native speakers use the language, not to tell them to speak differently.

Comment: @Anatolia "whose" derives its meaning from its antecedent "Uighur man". We understand that "... family believe Uighur man had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017.

Comment: @rjpond The theory is not flawed. I'm a native English speaker and I would have no hesitation in speaking/writing the OP's example. The addition of "he" not only sounds wrong, but is grammatically wrong. Note that the gap in subject position in the embedded _had been held_ clause is linked to "whose" in prenuclear position, and derives its interpretation from its antecedent "Uighur man".

Comment: @BillJ So am I. My point is that if educated speakers of standard English disagree then on what basis can you say that you are right and others wrong? Usage is the ultimate arbiter. How can any particular theory or framework have higher authority than that?

Comment: @rjpond You just don't get it, do you? I spend huge amounts of time with educated speakers of Standard English, and I can assure you that none of them would find anything grammatically wrong with it. In fact, there is actually a 'constraint' against using a personal pronoun (in the embedded clause) whose antecedent is the same as that of the relativised element. Can't you grasp the grammar here? Aren't you familiar with 'gapping'?

Comment: @BillJ I understand, but surely the constraint does not prohibit a phrase such as "a man who believes (that) he's God"? In which case, why in your view does it prohibit a phrase such as "a man whose family believe (that) he's in a camp" or "...(that) he had been held in a camp"?

Comment: @rjpond Sorry for the delay in responding. I'm trying to locate a paper I have on the constraint. As soon as I find it, I'll answer you question.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are ugly and unnecessarily hard to parse, and should have been rewritten.

However, the first one is simply wrong. Consider the following:

> The Chinese government has taken the rare step of formally confirming to the UN the death of a Uighur man who had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017.

> The Chinese government has taken the rare step of formally confirming to the UN the death of a Uighur man whose family had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017.

These sentences make sense, because the relationship between the subject - the man, or his family - and the verb - "had been held" - is clear.

But the original introduces a second level with the fact that it is the family who believe he had been held. It is an error to try and combine the "who" of "who had been held" with the "who" of "whose family".

The only way to fix this is to make it another relative clause (at the cost of making the sentence even more complex):

> The Chinese government has taken the rare step of formally confirming to the UN the death of a Uighur man who, his family believe, had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017.

but really the only proper thing to do here is to rewrite completely.

Comment: I don't see anything "ugly" about either of the sentences, or have any difficulty in parsing them . They both come from impeccable sources, The Guardian and The Wall Street Journal.

Comment: I am not qualified nor in position to evaluate English grammar but I believe that The Guardian would make grammatical errors very rarely if they make any.

Comment: I certainly find the sentence to be ugly and poorly written.  It's very nearly a garden path sentence, what with that long chain of modifiers.  @Anatolia: [Even major and respected newspapers make grammatical errors every single day.](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/community/inside-the-globe/public-editor-egregious-grammatical-errors-caught-by-globe-readers/article22721792/)

Comment: These comments, while well-intentioned, are hilarious. I worked as a newspaper sub-editor for many years and I know exactly how error-ridden journalists' copy can be; while the subs correct most of it, they can never expect to get everything. And that was in the days when there were many more subs than today, and much more time for them to work on each piece. Also, of course, the Guardian in particular has a reputation for being full of errors, so much so that its nickname is the Grauniad (admittedly this reputation is from more than 30 years ago).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't know that there could be many grammatical errors in newspaper articles with their native language. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Perhaps, but they did not make an error in this occasion, and nor did The Wall Street Journal. Your answer is misleading. The meaning is clear and the parsing is straightforward.

Comment: @BillJ that the meaning is evident does not make a sentence correct. In this case I agree with Daniel that while it's not really possible to parse it in any other way than the intended meaning, it's not correct English.

Comment: Is WSJ one wrong,too?

Comment: The OP's example is relatively "wordy", making it harder to focus on the specific syntactic element that at least some of us don't much like. But unless I'm very much mistaken, exactly the same "awkwardness" can be illustrated by ***They arrested a man whose wife says is innocent***. And unsurprisingly, I can't find a single written instance of the sequence [**a man whose wife says is**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+man+whose+wife+says+is%22) (or **...says was**) in Google Books. Doubtless because any "would-be" writers thereof thought better of it before putting pen to paper!

Comment: @MaciejStachowski That's simply not true. Both the examples are meaningful and grammatically correct. What grounds do you for saying they are incorrect?

Comment: @BillJ given that several people agree this is incorrect, claiming it is "simply not true" is well beyond what you can reasonably state.

Comment: No it isn't. As a grammarian, I am perfectly able to tell what is OK and what isn't and they are both grammatically sound.

Comment: Fine. If I were still a sub-editor and you submitted that sentence in your copy, I would change it.

Comment: Then you'd be wrong. Haven't you noticed how awful it _sounds_ when "he" is inserted in the embedded clause which, as you have failed to notice, already has a subject.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's example is relatively "wordy", making it harder to focus on the specific syntactic element that at least *some* native speakers don't like. But unless I'm very much mistaken, exactly the same "awkwardness" can be illustrated by...

> ***Police arrested a man whose wife says is innocent***

I could't find a single written instance of the sequence [**a man whose wife says is**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+man+whose+wife+says+is%22) (or **...says was**) in Google Books, which didn't surprise me in the least. But I *did* find one instance of [*a man whose wife says **he** is lazy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20man%20whose%20wife%20says%20he%20is%22), with that all-important pronoun ***he*** explicitly included, and one instance of [*a man whose wife claimed **that** he was...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20man%20whose%20wife%20claimed%20that%20he%20was%22), where I believe ***that*** also functions as a relative pronoun.

It's just my opinion, but personally I think that strictly speaking the construction is valid *with or without* an explicit pronoun reference, but ***all versions are "ugly"*** to many native speakers, so it would usually be better to go for more substantial rephrasing Perhaps *The wife of a man arrested by police says that he is innocent*.

Comment: Or "Police arrested a man believed by his wife to be innocent."

Comment: Yes, that's a better rephrasing than mine! Or at least, it *feels* like your version is a ***less substantial rephrasing*** than mine - and in this context, the less that ***has*** to be changed, the better.

Comment: But you can't say *"...the death of a Uighur man [whose family believe [he ___ had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017]]. The inclusion of the personal pronoun "he" as subject of the embedded content clause (in inner brackets) is not permitted since the subject position is already filled by "whose", i.e. "Uighur man", as subject.

Comment: @BillJ: I take it therefore that you believe my example *a man whose wife says **he** is lazy* is in fact "syntactically invalid". If so, I won't try to convince you otherwise, but so far as I'm concerned notions of correct syntax are fairly irrelevant here. The construction is inherently ugly, but from *my* perspective it's at least *slightly* better with the pronoun included.

Answer (score -1):

> [1] *The Chinese government has taken the rare step of formally confirming*
> *to the UN the death of a Uighur man* [*whose family believe* [ ___ *had been held*
> *in a Xinjiang internment camp since 2017*]].

> [2] *The Biden administration on Thursday barred U.S. companies from*
> *supplying Chinese entities* [*it said* [ ___ *were building supercomputers to*
> *help Beijing develop new weapons of mass destruction, including*
> *nuclear devices*]].

In [1], the relativised element is subject of the embedded "had been ..." clause. Since this clause already has a subject, the addition of a further one, i.e. the pronoun "he", would be ungrammatical. We understand that a Uighur man had been held in a Xinjiang internment camp ...

In [2] the relativised element is subject not of the relative clause but of the embedded "were building ..." clause. The addition of a relative word (or "that") at the beginning of the relative clause is permitted, though optional. We understand that Chinese companies were building supercomputers ...

Comment: @Anatolia. Why have you downvoted my answer, if indeed it was you?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I disagree. I would expect to see "who, his family believe, had been held" OR "whose family believe he had been held".

Comment: @KateBunting Your first suggestion is simply an alternant to the OP's one (from the Guardian). Your second suggestion won't work for the reason I gave in my answer.

Comment: @BillJ I did not downvote you.

Comment: I've been staring at that sentence for long enough that It's giving me a headache. Shouldn't it be "a man believed by his family to have been held in an internment camp since 2017." or "who was believed to have been held..."? There's something about using "whose family" that just doesn't sit right with me. It feels like the rest of the clause should be talking about his family, not him.

Comment: @ColleenV That's a good alternant, and one that some might prefer. Nevertheless, the version by The Guardian is grammatically correct.